# How To Change CSS or Class of "body" Element in Blazor

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm currently making a "Change Theme" button so that I can switch the whole page between "Dark Mode" and "Light Mode". But I can't find a way to change the background colour of the whole page.

Basically, I need to change the style of `<body>` (It's the only way I can come up with).
My thought is, when you click "Change Theme" button, the `<body>` element will be added a class "dark-theme".
And then I just simply define "dark-theme" in CSS like this:

```
body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
}

    body.dark-theme {
        background-color: #5A5A5A;
        color: #F2F2F2;
    }
```

I think this quite makes sense but as you can see below, I cannot access `<body>` element so there is no way for me to add class or change CSS of it.

**MainLayout.razor**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@using System.Web;
<div class="sidebar">
    <NavMenu />
</div>

<div>
    <LoginDisplay />
    <button id="change-theme-btn" @onclick="ThemeChanged">Change Theme</button>
    @Body
</div>

@code {
    bool isDark = false;
    private void ThemeChanged()
    {
        isDark = !isDark;
    }
}
```

So how do I change class or CSS of `<body>` element? Or if you have any alternative solution, please tell me. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have to use a `<body>` tag for this purpose?  
Can't you use any element that you can control inside `<app>` tag?  
I think you can spread a `<div>` element into full window size using CSS styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or if you want pure C# code without blazor:

```
public string BackgroundImage { get; set; }

<style>
    body 
    {
        background-image: url(@BackgroundImage);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-size: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: darkgray;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

Or, I use Nuget package BlazorStyled:

https://github.com/chanan/BlazorStyled

And here is a sample:

```
<Styled @bind-Classname="CanvasStyle">
    position: fixed;
    top: 18vh;
    left: 5%;
    width: 60%;
    height: 64vh;    
</Styled>

<div class=@CanvasStyle></div>
```

And here is a video I made for BlazorStyled if you care to watch:

https://youtu.be/frtetHgfdIo

Answer (score 9):

Blazor should have a simple way to do this but, at the moment, it doesn't. Hopefully it will one day soon.

I made a component to solve this problem. It allows you set the CSS class of the page's body element from a page or component. You can also set the lang attribute and the dir attribute to set the language and text-direction of the page. These were all the attributes I thought you might want to change but you could add more if you needed.

You can download the code here: https://github.com/BenjaminCharlton/BlazorBody

Or here's a summary of how to do it:

1. Make a little JavaScript file to manipulate the body element in scripts/BodyElement.js

```js
    var getBodyElement = function() {
        return document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    }
    
    var addCssClassToBody = function (cssClass) {
        var body = getBodyElement();
    
        if (!body.classList.contains(cssClass)) {
            body.classList.add(cssClass);
        }
    }
    
    
    var setLanguageOfBody = function (language) {
        var body = getBodyElement();
        body.lang = language;
    }
    
    var setTextDirectionOfBody = function (direction) {
        var body = getBodyElement();
        body.dir = direction;
    }
```

2. Place a link to your JavaScript in the  section of index.html

```html
<script src="/script/bodyelement.js"></script>
```

3. Make a little CSS class to test the result.

```css
    body {
        background: white;
        color: black;
    }
    
    body.danger {
        background: red;
        color: white;
    }
```

4. Make a BodyElement razor component that you can place on any page with properties you can set from the page.

```js
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@code {
    protected async override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (CssClass is { })
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("addCssClassToBody", CssClass);

        if (Language is { })
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setLanguageOfBody", Language);

        if (TextDirection is { })
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setTextDirectionOfBody", TextDirection);
    }

    [Parameter]
    public string? CssClass { get; set; } = null;

    [Parameter]
    public string? Language { get; set; } = null;

    [Parameter]
    public string? TextDirection { get; set; } = null;
}
```

5. Place the BodyElement razor component on any page where you wish to manipulate the  tag and set the properties

```html
    @page "/danger"
        <BodyElement CssClass="danger" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Just inject `IJSRuntime` and use that to call a JavaScript function to make this change.

In your component:

```
[Inject]
IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
```

Then:

```
private async Task ThemeChanged()
{
    isDark = !isDark;
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("MyInterop.ChangeTheme", isDark);
}
```

In your JS:

```
window.MyInterop = (function () {
    const _changeTheme = function (isDark) {
        if (isDark)
            document.body.classList.add('dark-theme');
        else
            document.body.classList.remove('dark-theme');
    };

    return {
        ChangeTheme: _changeTheme
    };
})();
```

If you haven't already, reference your JS file in `_Host.cshtml`, after the line to add the Blazor runtime.