# Convert static html page to Blazor Page

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor

I have build a static website, a long time ago, with [Nicepage](https://nicepage.com/).

But i want to convert this project into a Blazor project, so i can use some C# code.

To achieve this, i copy/paste the code of a html page, into a razor file, except the script tags (i put them into index.html).

The issue is that elements are not well render.

For example, i have an image that i want to be visible only on desktop, and not on mobile. After i switch the project on Blazor, the image is not visible on desktop and mobile. I saw that nicepage as a global css file, and a specific css file for the html page. So i add them into the razor page

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="nicepage.css" media="screen"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css" media="screen">`

But nothing happened.

So i would like to know if anyone has managed to create html page with Nicepage, and then use it in a Blazor project?

Thank you.

Comment: When you say `href="nicepage.css"` or `"home.css"` the application will try look inside the assembly where your application running. Ideally, all static resources are placed inside `wwwroot` folder. In your case either you need to fetch the css though `cdn` (if possible) or download the css file from _nicepage_ and place it `wwwroot` folder.

Comment: That nicepage.css should also be included in index.html, not in the razor file.

Comment: Hi, i included the nicepage.css in the index.html, and also placed .css files in wwwroot folder but the elements are not well arranged.

Comment: As mention in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61659727/how-to-change-css-or-class-of-body-element-in-blazor), i had to change the body class of my page.

Answer (score 0):

Blazor can be evil :). It works best with CSS (switching classes according to that field etc.) in my opinion. So if you want to display something on desktop do:

**1. code in CSS like**

```
    @media (max-width: 992px){
    .nameOfClass {
    display:none;
    }
 }
```

**2. Javascript:**
Do simple model, inject IJSRuntime, invoke it, create function **and use it as property in html part**

**Model -**

```
public class WindowDimension
{
public int Height { get; set; }
public int Width { get; set; }
}
```

**Inject IJSR -**
`@inject IJSRuntime JS` at top of .razor page

**Invoke e.g. in OnInitialize** also be aware of naming. I had some issues when I had it like HeightOfWindow etc.

```
@code{
int Height { get; set; }
int Width { get; set; }
    
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
          {    
            var dimension = await JS.InvokeAsync<WindowDimension>("getWindowDimensions");
            Height = dimension.Height;
            Width = dimension.Width;
          }
    }
```

**Create function in JS (can be only code in some JS file + do not forget to put  in index file.**

```
window.getWindowDimensions = function () {

  return {
    width: window.outerWidth,
    height: window.outerHeight
  };
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div style:"width: @Height">.....</div>
```