# .NET MAUI Blazor light/dark theme, load specific stylesheets via headcontent

Tags: css, .net-core, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I am creating a .net MAUI Blazor Hybrid app. In this, I want to create a dark and light theme *using css stylesheets* (no MudBlazor).

What I am trying now, is using a `lightMode.css` and `darkMode.css` that contain the correct colors for that theme. When dark mode is on, the MainLayout, and thus all pages, should use the `darkMode.css`

Example in `MainLayout.razor`:

```
<HeadContent>
    @if (isDark)
    {
        <link href="css/darkMode.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    }
    else
    {
        <link href="css/lightMode.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    }   
</HeadContent>

// HTML and c# here
```

However, this is not working. Looking at the page, none of this headcontent is in the  tag of the page, and adding them directly to the `index.html` page only results in the last of the files being applied.

I have looked at other solutions here, but they never mention how they achieved this with css, like in this post: [Light and dark theme for my Maui Blazor app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70265565/light-and-dark-theme-for-my-maui-blazor-app)

Any suggestions as to **how I can achieve a dark/light theme implementation with css**? Other ideas are welcome too, but this looks like the most simple one to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar to this [Theme Switching](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5323228/Blazor-Web-Assembly-WASM-Theme-Switching), you can go through the docs. For **stylesheet switching**, we need to alter the page head section. To do this, you can use the `HeadContent` component in the MainLayout.razor.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Like I showed in the code part of the post, headcontent is not working for some reason. But I'll take a look at that guide, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up doing doing it slightly differently, as I couldn't get HeadContent to work (probably since I removed the bootstrap parts as I wanted to do my own styling fully).

I ended up following a modified version of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63563797/17389553 by @benjamin. I do not add or remove classes to the HTML elements.

However, by using the such direct html/js element manipulators I simply get the `<head>` element, then the stylesheet `<link>` that contains the theme css file, and switch it out with light/dark depending on the toggle.

I will describe it a bit more in depth here.

My code:
In my `MainLayour.razor` class, I added this simple line which takes care of it:

```cs
<ElementManipulator IsDarkTheme="_isDark"></ElementManipulator>
```

Where `_isDark` is supplied by a simple toggle button.

This class is defined in `ElementManipulator.razor`:

```cs
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

@code {

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (IsDarkTheme is not null)
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("toggleThemeStyleSheet", IsDarkTheme);
    }

    [Parameter]
    public bool? IsDarkTheme { get; set; }
}
```

Which invokes the toggleThemeStyleSheet function in the javascript file `ElementManipulator.js`:

```js
var getHeadElement = function () {
    return document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
};

var toggleThemeStyleSheet = function (isDarkTheme) {
    let themeLink = getHeadElement().getElementsByClassName("theme")[0];
    let theme = isDarkTheme ? "darkTheme.css" : "lightTheme.css";
    themeLink.href = "_content/MyProject.UI/css/" + theme;
};
```

Which then swaps out the **lightTheme.css** with **darkTheme.css** and vice versa.